# MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail

Tags: android

I have been trying to load video thumbnails to my gridView. It is loading thumb nails very slowly if i use ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail.
So i decided to use MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail. But What is origld. and how can i pass this element to this method?
I have refer [MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688789/mediastore-video-thumbnails-getthumbnail-returns-null) link also. But it is not helpful for me

Comment: `But What is orgid.` What do you mean by this ? Where did you find this ?

Comment: public static Bitmap getThumbnail (ContentResolver cr, long origId, int kind, BitmapFactory.Options options) in API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public static Bitmap getThumbnail (ContentResolver cr, long origId, long groupId, int kind, BitmapFactory.Options options)
```

This method checks if the thumbnails of the specified image (origId) has been created. It will be blocked until the thumbnails are generated.

**Parameters**

- cr-   ContentResolver used to dispatch queries to MediaProvider.
- origId -  Original image id associated with thumbnail of interest.
- groupId - the id of group to which this request belongs
- kind- The type of thumbnail to fetch. Should be either MINI_KIND or MICRO_KIND
- options-  this is only used for MINI_KIND when decoding the Bitmap

As it defines the original image id of the video thumbnail you need to pass the image id of your video thumbnail in this parameter.

For more details Check out [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653526/how-to-find-origid-for-getthumbnail-when-taking-a-picture-with-camera-takepictur)

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnail (ContentResolver cr, long origId, long groupId, int kind, BitmapFactory.Options options)
// origid  is the Images.ImageColumns._ID
//groupid is the Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID
```

Comment: Hi GrlsHu.. i have tried your code. My imageview id is R.id.imageView_grid. I have passed it to getThumbNail mathod. But it returning null

Comment: Check out the link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks GrlsHu.. It is working. And it is faster than ThumbnailUtils. THanks again